# Need help resolving angular routing throwing a 500 error

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I cannot figure out how to resolve my 500 issue.  I do not know if i need to make a change in express or angular. Here is my main.js public  Any help is appreciated

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'], function ($interpolateProvider) {
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
        });
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider){
// $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
// $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        url:'/home',
        templateUrl:'/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
```

Here is my app.js on the server side

```
swig = new swig.Swig();
// swig.setDefaults({varControls: ['<%=','%>']});
app.engine('html',swig.renderFile);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

app.use('/api',apiRoutes);
```

Index.html I made sure to use the correct router syntax

```
  <div ui-view> 

  </div>
```

I am not going to the home page.  Not sure why.  I keep getting the error on my route **http://localhost:3000/#/home**

Comment: did you enabled `html5mode`?

Comment: Looks like something is failing on your server side. 500 means "Internal Server Error". Please check if you intialize "bodyParser" ! It would be great if you can share the full error stack from server side logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to where your home.html file is, ie, in which directory. Let's say it is in "allhtmls" directory. Then you will need to do two things:

```
app.use('/myhome', express.static(__dirname + '/allhtmls'));// or use /client/allhtmls if under client directory - best practice

state('home',{
        url:'/home',
        templateUrl:'/myhome/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
```

Comment: I could not thank you enough!!   I am using express router so my syntax was a little different.  However, saw what you did with app.use and problem solved from there.  I have spend 2 days on this.